# Selenium3 Python3 how to get url from attribute style="background-image: ur,' " and there is a url"

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, selenium3

ho to get url from attribute url i mean the url himself in style? style="width: 433px; height: 510px; background-image: url(https://cs7056.vk.me/c635104/v635104607/1c316/ADzy-2WY8pw.jpg)"  Selenium3 Python3 easy for you!

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoAlertPresentException
import re
import time


url = 'https://vk.com/uporols_you'
driver                          = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='C:/Users/PANDEMIC/AppData/Local/Mozilla/geckodriver.exe')

def login(driver):
    log_page                    = driver.get('https://login.vk.com/?act=login')
    find_login_input            = driver.find_element_by_id('login_form').find_element_by_id('email').send_keys('+77782303865')
    find_password_input         = driver.find_element_by_id('login_form').find_element_by_id('pass').send_keys('pass')
    find_button                 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@id="login_button"]').click()
    time.sleep(5)



def get_photo_from_page(driver):
    driver.get(url)
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_class_name('popup_box_container').find_element_by_class_name('box_title_wrap').find_element_by_class_name('box_x_button').click()
    except:
        print('nope nothing')

    for i in range(2):
        scrol_down = driver.find_element_by_id('public_wall').find_element_by_id('wall_more_link').click()
        time.sleep(2)

    tut = []
    #t = (a[@class="page_post_thumb_wrap image_cover  page_post_thumb_last_column page_post_thumb_last_row"])
    for ii in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[@style]'):
        o = ii.get_attribute('style')
        print(o)
    #soup = BeautifulSoup(htlm, 'lxml')
    #im = soup.find_all('a', class_="'page_post_thumb_wrap image_cover  page_post_thumb_last_column page_post_thumb_last_row'")
    #print(htlm)
    #for a in im:
    #   s = a.get('data-src_big').split('|')[0]
    #   tut.append(s)
    #print(tut) 

    #for num, link in enumerate(tut, start=1):
    #   p = requests.get(link)
    #   out = open("img%s.jpg" % (num), 'wb')
    #   out.write(p.content)
    #   out.close()


def main():
    login(driver)
    get_photo_from_page(driver)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that particular case, you could just parse the style string that you were already able to gather with your script.

Just add this function to your code:

```
def parse_style_attribute(style_string):
    if 'background-image' in style_string:
        style_string = style_string.split(' url("')[1].replace('");', '')
        return style_string
    return None
```

This is a simple string parsing which extract the url if there is "background-image" in the string, or return None if there is no image.

You can then use it in your code:

```
links = list()
for ii in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[@style]'):
    o = ii.get_attribute('style')
    links.append(parse_style_attribute(o))
links = [link for link in links if link is not None]
```

Comment: but how to remove  this [None, None, None, None, 'https://pp.vk.me/c638718/v638718210/1b8a6/Fwbewm68Alg.jpg', from this 'https://cs7056.vk.me/c635104/v635104607/105ca/AmvyePsSzyM.jpg',

Comment: You could use a list comprehension to get rid of the None. See the edit of my answer.