# How to get background-image from inline css using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, value-of-css-property

Using python how can I get the background image using selenium? Which has an inline CSS? I want to get the image URL from the background-image: url()

```
<div id="pic" class="pic" data-type="image" style=" background-image: url(http://test.com/images/image.png;); height: 306px; background-size: cover;"></div>
```

Comment: FYI! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42187922/selenium3-python3-how-to-get-url-from-attribute-style-background-image-ur

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To get the background image you need to use [`value_of_css_property(property_name)`](https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.value_of_css_property) method and you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  import re

  my_property = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.pic#pic[data-type='image']"))).value_of_css_property("background-image")
  print(re.split('[()]',my_property)[1])
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  import re

  my_property = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='pic' and @id='pic'][@data-type='image']"))).value_of_css_property("background-image")
  print(re.split('[()]',my_property)[1])
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  test.com/images/image.png
  ```

---

### Update

As the url is getting wrapped up with in double quotes i.e. `"..."` you can use the following solution:

```
print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='pic' and @id='pic'][@data-type='image']"))).value_of_css_property("background-image").split('"')[1])
```

---

### References

You can find a couple relevant discussions related to:

- Retrieving the background in [How to convert #ffffff to #fff or #fff to #ffffff while asserting the background color rgb(255,255,255) returned by Selenium getCssValue("background")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54767206/how-to-convert-ffffff-to-fff-or-fff-to-ffffff-while-asserting-the-background)
- Retrieving a sub-string in [How to retrieve a sub-string from a string that changes dynamically with respect to multiple delimiters through Selenium in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52121094/how-to-retrieve-a-sub-string-from-a-string-that-changes-dynamically-with-respect/52121146#52121146)

Comment: That was helpful but I am getting the value as  "url( "http://test.com/images/image.png") " how to get that exact link which is inside the url

Comment: @Anjali Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: @DebanjanB your approach gave the result with " " at both ends but adding [ "  ] this pattern to the result gave me the exact URL. Thank you for your solution

Comment: @Anjali Going by the HTML the _css_ property is `background-image: url(http://test.com/images/image.png;);` and have no quotes around. So the webapp may be adding the quotes to the _string_ which we can't recognize unless we run the apps. I understand adding **`"`** within the pattern solved your issue.

Comment: @Anjali Can you check and update me the result using the alternative option I have added as an update to the answer if that works?

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.pic#pic[data-type='image']"))).get_attribute("href"))
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the `URL` You need to use `regular expression`.
In order to use regular expression `Import re` and then use the following regular expression.

```
import re
itemimage=WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div#pic"))).value_of_css_property("background-image")
print(re.search("(?P<url>http?://[^\s;]+)", itemimage).group("url"))
```

**Output**:

```
http://test.com/images/image.png
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 my_setup = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//body/div[@class='container']/div[@class='row']/div[@class='card-stack']/div/div[1]/div[1]"))).value_of_css_property("background-image")

image_url = re.split('[()]',my_setup)[1]
```

use this actually its working fine for me..

main things..

```
.value_of_css_property("background-image")
```

not working for a list