# How to get the hover button background color of a website using selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait, value-of-css-property

Hello I am using python selenium to get some css propertiew of a button. I need also the hover background color. The css is like this:

```
.overview .add-to-cart-button:hover, .variant-overview .add-to-cart-button:hover {
background-color: #b41733;}
```

My code is this:

```
    from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.support.color import Color
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get('https://www.inshoes.gr/andrikes-zones-andrikes-zones-dermatines-diplis-opseos-33000481-kamel-mavro')


background_color = driver.find_element_by_id('addtocartbutton-7531').value_of_css_property('background-color')
text_color = driver.find_element_by_id('addtocartbutton-7531').value_of_css_property('color')
hex_color = Color.from_string(background_color).hex
hex_text_color = Color.from_string(text_color).hex
print(hex_color)
print(hex_text_color)
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: What does `print(hex_color)` and `print(hex_text_color)` prints?

Comment: @DebanjanB the background color and the text color of a button. I need the background color when I hover the button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To retrieve the hover button background color of the [WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52782684/what-is-the-difference-between-webdriver-and-webelement-in-selenium/52805139#52805139) using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) first you need to [*Mouse Hover*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57901045/scrape-website-with-dynamic-mouseover-event/57903003#57903003) inducing [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50468629/python-selenium-wait-until-element-is-fully-loaded/50474905#50474905) and then use [*value_of_css_property()*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59103063/how-to-get-background-image-from-inline-css-using-selenium/59103600#59103600) and you can use the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

Code Block:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=options)
driver.get("https://www.inshoes.gr/andrikes-zones-andrikes-zones-dermatines-diplis-opseos-33000481-kamel-mavro")
basket = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#addtocartbutton-7531")))
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(basket).click().perform()
print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#addtocartbutton-7531"))).value_of_css_property('background-color'))
```

Console Output:

```
rgba(242, 35, 65, 1)
```

**Note** : You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: this returns the background color of the button, not the hover color

Comment: @user15924442 I think your question was about _the hover background color_ and the HTML `background-color: #b41733;` and your comment _`I need the background color when I hover the button`_. Having said that, possibly I gave you all the hints and details.