# Adjusting dynamic input fields when changing the type of the input field

Tags: javascript, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a little challenge when testing a website. Just wanted to see if you folks have any suggestions on this. The story behind this is that I need to mask the input fields for the screenshots when the test has been executed as we are sharing the data with other teams. Before the script I am running JS with 'document***.type="password";', but when script starts to type, then input type is changed back to the type of text. Also, class changes from class="is-invalid" to class="is-focused   is-invalid" when it's active. Also, I could of course change the type after I have typed the value, but even tho when I click the next field, the class changes. When I have filled the first input field it checks the data against the server and the class is of course changed.

I have an input field when inactive:

```html
<input ref="input" value="input field" id="id-for-unified-text-input--14fe" name="unified-text-input-14fe" type="text" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" placeholder="ABC123" class="is-invalid">
```

And the input field when active"

```html
<input ref="input" value="input field" id="id-for-unified-text-input--14fe" name="unified-text-input-14fe" type="text" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" placeholder="ABC123" class="is-focused   is-invalid">
```

Any suggestions from a fellow testers, how could I fix this? Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

As pretty much evident from the HTML the `<input>` field whenever recieves the [focus_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59518772/how-to-focus-object-in-selenium-web-driver/59521886#59521886) the classname `is-focused` added.

This addition of *classname* is pretty much controled through the attributes, presumably the [css_properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59103063/how-to-get-background-image-from-inline-css-using-selenium/59103600#59103600) of the parent elements.

As as conclusion, it would be difficult to mask the *password* field characters from the clientside and have to be controled from the Application Server side.

Comment: Alright, thanks @DebanjanB. Will try to  check with developer team.