# Selenium: How to extract the CSS background-image value

Tags: python, selenium, background-image, webdriverwait, value-of-css-property

HTML:

```
<div class="__section-image" style="background-image: url(&quot;/img/all/05_element/continentImg/1.png&quot;);"></div>
```

at this html part how can I locate the background-image?

Answer (score 2):

To get the background image you need to use [`value_of_css_property(property_name)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59103600/7429447) method and inducing [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50474905/7429447) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  import re

  my_property = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[class='__section-image']"))).value_of_css_property("background-image")
  print(re.split('[()]',my_property)[1])
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  import re

  my_property = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='__section-image']"))).value_of_css_property("background-image")
  print(re.split('[()]',my_property)[1])
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```